# Replacing closing HTML tags with HTML tag + \n

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to replace generally closing html tags with the closing tag + a line break, i found similar posts here on SO, none really helped me to accomplish what I'm looking for.

`</li>` would be `</li>\n`

`<img some property />` would be `<img some property />\n`

I managed to do that in php with the following funtion, which works well:

```
 public static function addLBinHTML($htmlcode){

     $pattern= array('~(</.*?>)~','(/>)');
     $replace= array('${1} Hallo \n  ','/>\n  ');

     return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $htmlcode);
}
```

I'm trying to do the same in JavaScript / jQuery and I'm failing on getting the variable(in php regex `${1}`).

I tried with .split .join and with .replace, and I think .replace is the right way to go.

Here is what I got (my last and hopefully closest attempt)

```
function setLinebreaks(taID){

   var strContent = $('#'+taID).val();
   var regex = new RegExp("</.*?>", "gi");

    strContent.replace(regex, "${1} \n   ")
              .replace(/\/>/g,'/> \n    ');

   console.log(strContent);
   $('#'+taID).val(strContent);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to capture the regular expression with brackets, **assign the replaced string** and replace `${1}` by `$1`:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(</.*?>)", "gi");

strContent = strContent.replace(regex, "$1 \n   ")
                       .replace(/\/>/g,'/> \n    ');
```

Or you can simply put the `replace` methods into the `val` function.