# Replace HTML closing tags with HTML tags + \n Analysis

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to replace HTML closing tags with HTML tags + \n. I've found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396013/replacing-closing-html-tags-with-html-tag-n)

```
var regex = new RegExp("(</.*?>)", "gi");

strContent = strContent.replace(regex, "$1 \n   ")
                   .replace(/\/>/g,'/> \n    ');
```

Could someone explain to me what is happening in the above code? Why is a regex declared then replaced? What does each part mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first regex `(</.*?>)` is searching for all closing tags of the form `</span>` or `</div>` and selecting the tag as a group. This group is replaced with the group as found plus a new line.

The second regex, `/\/>/` is looking for the last two characters of tags that are of the form `<img />` or `<input />`. The `\` is escaping the second `/`. Then  those two characters are replaced with the same characters plus a new line.

Answer (score 1):

It's the regex replace function.

It can also be written like this:

```
strContent = strContent.replace(new RegExp("(</.*?>)", "gi"), "$1 \n   ").replace(/\/>/g,'/> \n    ');
```

Does that make more sense?

The author decided to declare the Regex object seperately an then referenced it later as input to the Replace method

I can only speculate, but I guess it was done for debugging reasons.